# If the priorities of 2 jobs are the same, will the second job wait until the first one finishes?

Tags: cpu, process-priority

Let me suppose a system has one cpu.

If 2 jobs started at different times but the priorities are the same(20, 20), the job that started later than the other will wait until the earlier one finishes?

Could you help me to know this?

Thank you in advance.

P.s. Sorry for my bad english.

Comment: No 2 jobs with the same priority will run concurrently, with only 1 CPU or Core the CPU will swap between the 2 jobs equally!

Comment: Thank you. So 2 users don't need to occupy only a half of the cpu cores... Each person can run job with all cores.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is a very basic explanation of how time sharing works:

There are (very short) time slices after which a running job has to give up the CPU to give way to other waiting jobs that are ready to run. This is to guarantee that even if a job is a purely calculating one, it can't block the CPU forever. When the job is forced to leave the CPU and would still have work to do, it is put back in the queue of the 'ready to run' jobs in a position corresponding to its priority.

If a job has to wait (e.g. to read from memory or to do an I/O - which is extremely slow compared to the speed of the CPU) it also gives up the CPU until it is woken up by an interrupt when the I/O is done. Then it will be put again into the queue of the 'ready to run' jobs.

This works even on a single core / single thread system.

So seen from outside both jobs will take turns at the CPU and will seem to be running simultaneously.

This behavior is very important for fairness: Imagine one job doing endless calculations (calculating all prime numbers up to 10^10) and a second one that only wants to `echo hello` which would have to wait until the first job has finished.

Comment: Thank you for answering! I can understand it now with your help.